# KSQLDB : Dynamic KTable creation on topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

In my case, daily data is getting produced in one topic. I want KSQLDB server to create two tables daily for today and yesterday. For example, Today-Table and Yesterday-Table are two KTables of same topic conditioning that Today-Table contains today’s data and Yesterday-Table contain yesterday’s data. It is pretty achievable when it comes to static creation.
But what I need here is, for next day it should automatically toggle today’s data as yesterday’s data and next day’s data as today’s data and so on.
As for tomorrow, today is yesterday.
Setup server is confluent cloud itself.
Is it achievable with KSQLDB? How can I do that? What should be the prerequisites?

Please put some light in this case,
Thanks.

Comment: I imagine timezones will be an issue; e.g. what is "midnight" that separates two days? Overall, seems like the solution is a cron script that will create both tables on a nightly basis with a WHERE query that filters the timestamps between two dates. KSQL itself cannot do this and you'll need some external API/SQL calls

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your point. If data come for today and yesterday in real-time that is piece of cake to filter, but day is coming for just today. And Ksqldb needs to backtrack to earliest and restart checking which is quite tough.

Comment: But at the end of "today", you will have data for "yesterday", so every night you can use something like `CREATE TABLE yesterday AS SELECT FROM today`, then delete and recreate the today table with a new filter.

Comment: I get your point, but somebody needs to trigger it every night right? My point here was, how I can achieve it without any manual trigger? how can I auto tune it in KSQLDB

Comment: Like I said, you can use `cron` and run any scripts. Ksql cannot do this on its own

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks, that's helpful.